# Installing angular 12.0.1 for Node.js 14.21.3 in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, node-modules

I am trying to install Angular 12.0.1 in Node.js v14.21.3 in Ubuntu 22.04.

I get this error after installation when I want to check the version:

```
(base) mona@ada:~$ sudo npm install -g @angular/cli@12.0.1
npm WARN deprecated sourcemap-codec@1.4.8: Please use @jridgewell/sourcemap-codec instead
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@1.1.2: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
/usr/bin/ng -> /usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng

> @angular/cli@12.0.1 postinstall /usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli
> node ./bin/postinstall/script.js

? Would you like to share anonymous usage data with the Angular Team at Google under
Google’s Privacy Policy at https://policies.google.com/privacy? For more details and
how to change this setting, see https://angular.io/analytics. Yes
+ @angular/cli@12.0.1
added 235 packages from 182 contributors in 15.206s
(base) mona@ada:~$ ng v
Node.js version v14.21.3 detected.
The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of v18.13.

Please update your Node.js version or visit https://nodejs.org/ for additional instructions.
```

I installed node v14.X using the following:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x -o setup_14.sh

sudo sh ./setup_14.sh

sudo apt update

sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

```
mona@ada:~$ node -v
v14.21.3
```

Updates:

I followed https://angular.io/guide/versions and installed node `v14.15.0` and then proceeded to install `Angular 12.0.1`. However, I still get the same message:

```
(dimo-labeling) mona@ada:~/dimo-labeling/frontend$ node -v
v14.21.3
(dimo-labeling) mona@ada:~/dimo-labeling/frontend$ sudo apt-get remove nodejs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  nodejs
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 441 not upgraded.
After this operation, 121 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 479633 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing nodejs (14.21.3-deb-1nodesource1) ...
dpkg: warning: while removing nodejs, directory '/usr/lib/node_modules' not empty so not removed
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
(dimo-labeling) mona@ada:~/dimo-labeling/frontend$ node -v
bash: /usr/bin/node: No such file or directory
(dimo-labeling) mona@ada:~/dimo-labeling/frontend$ nvm install 14.15.0
Downloading and installing node v14.15.0...
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.15.0/node-v14.15.0-linux-x64.tar.xz...
######################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################### 100.0%
Computing checksum with sha256sum
Checksums matched!
Now using node v14.15.0 (npm v6.14.8)
(dimo-labeling) mona@ada:~/dimo-labeling/frontend$ node -v
v14.15.0
(dimo-labeling) mona@ada:~/dimo-labeling/frontend$ npm install -i @angular/cli@12.0.1
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported

> core-js@3.12.0 postinstall /home/mona/dimo-labeling/frontend/node_modules/core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

Thank you for using core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock/core-js ) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library!

The project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on Open Collective or Patreon: 
> https://opencollective.com/core-js 
> https://www.patreon.com/zloirock 

Also, the author of core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock ) is looking for a good job -)


> @angular/cli@12.0.1 postinstall /home/mona/dimo-labeling/frontend/node_modules/@angular/cli
> node ./bin/postinstall/script.js

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

+ @angular/cli@12.0.1
added 1327 packages from 1176 contributors and audited 1332 packages in 15.114s

86 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 262 vulnerabilities (2 low, 163 moderate, 79 high, 18 critical)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
(dimo-labeling) mona@ada:~/dimo-labeling/frontend$ ng v
Node.js version v14.15.0 detected.
The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of v18.13.

Please update your Node.js version or visit https://nodejs.org/ for additional instructions.
```

[image]

Comment: so, uhm... use a version of angular that supports nodejs 14 or use a version of nodejs that supports angular 12.0.1. What is your question? All of the information to solve this is in the response.

Comment: @KevinB Please have a look at my updated post under Update: -- even with the compatible version for Angular 12.0.X I get the same message.

Comment: @DM I understand however the author code is not compatible with newest Angular -- here is the error I get with new angular / TS https://github.com/pderoovere/dimo-labeling/issues/4

Comment: That specific error is due to the update to `@angular/material` from version 14 to 15 ([see the blog](https://blog.angular.io/angular-v15-is-now-available-df7be7f2f4c8)). You might be able to get up to Angular 14 if you don't have other errors.

Comment: @DM I look into it and will report separately if I couldn't fix it.

Comment: The author had updated the repo 3 weeks ago with same version of angular as in OP

Comment: You have something funky going on in your environment, likely with your `PATH`. If you'd installed version `12.0.x` of the Angular CLI, it shouldn't be capable of throwing such an error message according to [the relevant source code](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/12.0.x/packages/angular/cli/lib/cli/index.ts#L26-L31). What does running `ng --version` in your shell yield?

Comment: @esqew  mona@ada:~$ ng --version
Node.js version v14.15.0 detected.
The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of v18.13.

Please update your Node.js version or visit https://nodejs.org/ for additional instructions.

Comment: How about `which ng`? Where is that executable you're running actually installed? Have you installed `ng` through any alternative means in the past that's still mucking up your shell's resolution of the version you've explicitly installed?

Comment: @esqew $ which ng
/usr/local/bin/ng
 I installed the newer version as in https://github.com/pderoovere/dimo-labeling/issues/4 but uninstalled it. Do you have a suggestion for a command to try?

Comment: Quick question: _why_? Are you trying to uplift an ancient codebase to the current versions of node and angular but you need to start at the bottom in order to perform the uplift one version at a time? (Because if not, why are you using angular 12 and Node 14 at all, given that both are "dead" versions?)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans this is a valid question. Thanks for your comment. I have zero knowledge of Angular and I have been trying to reproduce the `BOP-compatibility` branch of https://github.com/pderoovere/dimo-labeling and in https://github.com/pderoovere/dimo-labeling/blob/main/frontend/package.json author has stated Angular 12.0.1 and it has been updated 3 weeks ago. I modified the package.json for angular 17 and got this bug https://github.com/pderoovere/dimo-labeling/issues/4 trying to be compatible with author hence 12.0.1

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/ng` is *probably* a symlink elsewhere - if it is, the command `readlink $(which ng)` should reveal its *actual* location and might provide you with a hint as to where this is still installed. I don't recommend mucking about in your system files unless you have a 100% understanding about where this particular installation of `ng` came from originally, and even so you should be using the same package utility to uninstall it and prevent it from continuing to mess with your preferred installation of `ng`.

Comment: @esqew I installed it using `npm install -i @angular/cli@12.0.1` and `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli@12.0.1` and `(dimo-labeling) mona@ada:~$ readlink $(which ng)
../lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng.js` -- also I tried to uninstall and it still doesn't get uninstall `$ npm uninstall -g @angular/cli` and `$ npm cache clean --force` and I still get same message when I enter `$ng`

Comment: Please don't use the comment thread for elaborating with additional details and steps you ran: [put those in your post](/help/how-to-ask) and talk about them there so folks get all the information they need from reading the post itself.

Comment: I can't reproduce these problems a random Ubuntu 20 VM, since that's from roughly the same time as angular 12 and node 14, so... maybe give that a shot?  I installed `nvm`, told that to install node 14, cloned the repo and switched to the branch you indicated, then ran npm install and npm start. No errors, things just work.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans are you able to reproduce it on Ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: That's like trying to run windows 7 software on Windows 11: I'm not even going to try, just use the version of Ubuntu that was around back when angular 12 and node 14 were, too. (live"cd", VM, docker image, _lots_ of options)